# Position Sticky Element Shifts when scrollbar appears

Tags: css, position, scrollbar, overflow, sticky

I have an element that has overflow:auto style.
So when the scrollbar appears , the container content shifts to the left.

Similar situation arises , when I have an element with position:sticky and right:0, it shifts to the left when scrollbar appears in its container.

How to solve this?

I am expecting that the content should not shift on scrollbar coming and is it possible only through css?

Comment: Sounds like standard behavior. Do you expect the sticky content to be positioned on top of the scrollbar?

Comment: you mean like it shifts a bit to the left to give space on the screen for the scrollbar?

Comment: TIP: Questions like this are always a lot easier to answer, and you get a better answer for your situation, if you provide some code. This is called a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Tim R  Yes , kind of. I don't want the scrollbar to take extra space

Comment: @Dhia Yes , it shifts the column (element) which makes the UI distorted.